# VBA column reference from cell range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have what might be a very simple a question regarding the row and column attributes of a cell dimension.

For context - I have three sheets, one of which is a master sheet. I am copying data from each of the two data sheets into the master, based on column headers. Not all the column headers in the master tab appear in the data sheets. I have written the following code, which loops through the first data sheet (ws2) and pastes columns of data into the relevant columns in the master sheet.

```
Sub master_sheet_data()

'Variables
Dim ws1_xlRange As Range
Dim ws1_xlCell As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Dim ws2_xlRange As Range
Dim ws2_xlCell As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim ws3_xlRange As Range
Dim ws3_xlCell As Range
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Dim valueToFind As String
Dim lastrow As String

'Assign variables to specific worksheets/ranges
'These will need to be updated if changes are made to the file.
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Refined event data - all")
Set ws1_xlRange = ws1.Range("A1:BJ1")

Set ws2 = Worksheets("Refined event data")
Set ws2_xlRange = ws2.Range("A1:BJ1")

Set ws3 = Worksheets("Refined ID data")
Set ws3_xlRange = ws3.Range("A1:BJ1")

'Loop through all the column headers in the all data tab
For Each ws1_xlCell In ws1_xlRange
    valueToFind = ws1_xlCell.Value
        'Loop for - Refined event data tab
        'check whether column headers match. If so, paste column from event tab to relevant column in all data tab
        For Each ws2_xlCell In ws2_xlRange
            If ws2_xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
                ws2_xlCell.EntireColumn.Copy
                ws1_xlCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            End If
        Next ws2_xlCell
        'Loop for - Refined MASH data tab
        'check whether column headers match. If so, paste column from MASH tab to relevant column in all data tab
        'ensure data is pasted below data from previous loop and only pulling data with '0' in col O, 'N' in col Q in MASH tab
         For Each ws3_xlCell In ws3_xlRange
            If ws3_xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
                ws3_xlCell.End(xlUp).Copy
                lastrow = ws1.Cells(rows.Count,"..." ).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Range("..." & lastRow).Select    
                Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            End If
        Next ws3_xlCell


Next ws1_xlCell

End Sub
```

The problem comes when looping through the second data sheet (ws3). I need these columns to be pasted at the next empty row of the relevant columns in the master sheet. I was planning to use the `lastrow` dimension to calculate this but it needs a row/column reference to define it. Unfortunately the column (`"..."`) is tied into the `ws1_xlCell` dimension, which moves as the loop is processed.

Is there a way to extract a column reference from a cell that is defined as a dimension?

Cheers,
Ant

Comment: `lastrow = ws1.Cells(rows.Count,ws3_xlCell.column ).End(xlUp).Row + 1` ? Not sure if that is the right column variable but hopefully you get the idea. You should use Find or Match to avoid looping through every cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @SJR - the complete line of code in question is

```
lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, ws1_xlCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Range(ws1_xlCell.Column & lastrow).Select
```

Comment: Could do with getting out of the habit of using `Active` & `Select`.  If one row says `Select` and the next says `Selection` then just replace `Selection` with whatever you selected....  `Range("..." & lastRow).Pastespecial....` (there's a link to a post on the subject, but can never remember it).